# generate javascript using xml and xsl

Tags: javascript, xml, xslt

I have tried every solution I found on here and even a larger Google search but nothing seems to work.  Here is my problem...  I have data that is in XML that I would like to visualize using the Google Visualization API.  I was hoping I could simply use XSL to generate what I need instead of doing anything with data sources (I have my reasons).  But the javascript code does not show up in my output.  Is this even possible?

My XML

```
<DocumentElement>
  <QueryResults>
    <Year>2000</Year>
    <Population>100000</Population>
  </QueryResults>
  <QueryResults>
    <Year>2001</Year>
    <Population>105000</Population>
  </QueryResults>
</DocumentElement>
```

My XSL file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8"/>
<xsl:template match="/">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>     
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('visualization', '1', {packages:['barchart']});
        google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

        function drawChart() {
            var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

            data.addColumn('string', 'Year');
            data.addColumn('string', 'Population');
            data.addRows(2); // hard-coded for testing

            <xsl:for-each select="DocumentElement/QueryResults">
                data.setValue(0, 0, '<xsl:value-of select="Year"/>');
                data.setValue(0, 1, '<xsl:value-of select="Population"/>');                 
            </xsl:for-each>

            var chart = new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
            chart.draw(data, {width: 400, height: 240, is3D: true, title: 'Population'});
        }
    </script>

    <div id="chart_div">&#160;</div>

</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My output

```
<!-- notice no javascript -->
<div id="chart_div"> </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

What does the line in your XML that includes the XSL file look like? I added these two lines to the top of the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="test.xsl"?>
```

The result was correct, though the graph didn't actually show the data properly. It was at least called.

Comment: What I pasted is exactly what the XML output I have to work with looks like.  Then a 3rd party component renders based on the XML and my XSL...  It sounds like I might have to dig into the renderer to find out what is going on.  Thanks.

Comment: Which 3rd party component, if you don't mind my asking? Like I mentioned, I just copied your inputs to test.xml and test.xsl and added the stylesheet directive, and it works, so you're on the right track. I think it's probably just something with your toolchain.

Comment: It is XML spit out from the DNN reports module and I am seeing if I can use the built-in XSL visualization.  I have it working using the HTML visualizer but it is ugly.  And if you are not familiar with DNN then this probably means nothing to you. :)