# Dynamic es6 module loading via <script type="module>

Tags: module, ecmascript-6, script-tag, transpiler

I'd like to use the es6-module-loader polyfill with the "module" tag in the browser: https://github.com/ModuleLoader/es6-module-loader#module-tag

It works by traversing all the files imported, looking for import/export tags and transpiling them. Traceur is the default due to babel no longer supporting dynamic, in-browser use.

The problem is that traceur transpiles all es6 features, while I want to transpile *only* the import/export statements due to good es6 browser support now (Canary is > 95% es6 complete!).

I tried turning off all the options that looked right, see below, but got lots of odd errors. I have not yet tried using the earlier babel 5.x in-browser for transpiling.

Is there any simple way to to get `<script src="module">` working? I presume es6-module-loader is the best approach but any suggestion appreciated! A better set of traceur options? Try babel 5.x?

> System.traceurOptions = { arrowFunctions: false, blockBinding: false, classes: false, computedPropertyNames: false, defaultParameters: false, destructuring: false, forOf: false, generators: false, numericLiterals: false, propertyMethods: false, propertyNameShorthand: false, restParameters: false, spread: false, symbols: false, templateLiterals: false, unicodeEscapeSequences: false, unicodeExpressions: false }

Comment: Just curious as to why you're doing this as opposed to bundling modules with a loader?

Comment: Good question. Mainly our group wants to 1) minimize/simplify workflow 2) be as close as possible to the browser module loader when it is implemented. Webpack, browserify, etc all are great, and maybe I just don't get them at this point. I presumed es6 would cut down on them rather than add to the workflow soup! And bundling? With http2/ bundling may be an anti-pattern.

Comment: Wanting to be as close to the ground to http2 modules is a reasonable response---the overhead in regards to workflow by module bundling with webpack is very low if you just download a boilerplate and be done with it. You can get more into it over a weekend if you need to do some interesting customizations. I think that's preferable until browsers load modules natively

Comment: I think presuming bundling won't be important with http2 isn't quite right. http2 will still have tons of round-trip requests unless you've configured your server with http2 push, and the only way push will work well is by having walked the dependency graph of your files just like a bundler would. You're never going to get around having some kind of dependency-processing step if you want performant loading in production.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generate javascript using xml and xsl](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160304/generate-javascript-using-xml-and-xsl)